# Where should I put removeObserver from NSNotification

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnotification

I have three `viewControllers`, and I'm trying to send a notification from `viewController` 3 to `viewController` 1 and 2. I think the best way to do this is to use `NSNotification`. Here's what I have so far:

**In class C** - Post the notification

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotficationName:@"Updated "object:self];
```

In class B

**In class A and B** - Register first for the notification

```
// viewDidLoad
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleUpdate:) name:@"Updated" object:nil];

-(void)handleUpdate:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSLog(@"recieved");
}
```

This works so far. But when I de-register it in class A and B:

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
```

The `handleUpdate` method doesn't get called. So the obvious problem is when I `removeObserver's` for the `notification`.

My question is, if everything I did so far is correct, why isn't it working when I remove the `removeObserver`? If it's not correct, where can I `removeObserver's`?

Comment: Thanks!! Can't believe it was that simple!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything you did is right. this is how the notification work. 
If your class A,B always need to handle the update, you won't removeObserver. 
Because you add your "addObserver" in viewDidLoad. it means you addObserver only once. 
The normal error is that you add  "addObserver" in "viewWillAppear" or "viewDidAppear", it will add more than once observer in the class. Then, you have to removeObserver in viewDidDisappear.

Comment: No, not everything is right and yes, you must remove the observer at some point - before the class is deallocated.

Comment: @rmaddy So should I insert the removeObserver in dealloc method?

Comment: @Jessica Yes, just as Reming Hsu suggested.